# Can't complie some modules under linux kernel 5.0.7 on fedora 29

Tags: linux-kernel, vmware-workstation, fedora-29

I can't compile modules and load them into my kernel 5.0.7.

When I tried to install them, I saw:

```
Falied to run '/usr/bin/vmware-modconfig'  
--icon='vmware-workstation' 
--appname='VMware' --gcc='/usr/lib64/ccache/gcc' --
headers='/lib/modules/5.0.7-200.fc29.x86_65/build/include' as user root.
```

Unable to copy the user's Xauthorization file.

What should I do to fix that problem?

Comment: How are you compiling your module ? What is the command used to install it ?

Comment: @bornfree first i compile them by gui, it means i pressed install button and error ocurred. Also used terminal with the same results - vmware-modconfig --console --install-all , but this command hadn't worked too.

Comment: are you running this with the root user or sudo?

Comment: @steve tryed both and didn't work. When i install vmware under 4.18 kernel, everything worked properly, but uner new version of kernel nothing worked.